# Code Contracts throws MethodAccess Exception when unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, exception, resharper, code-contracts

I'm not quite sure why, but when I enable runtime contract checking, I'm getting a `MethodAccessException` during unit testing. I use the *Machine.Specifications* test framework and the ReSharper/dotCover test runner. When I test my assembly containing code contracts, I get this `MethodAccessException`:

```
Machine.Specifications.SpecificationException Should be of type System.ArgumentNullException but is of type System.MethodAccessException
    at BusinessLogic.Specifications.When_testing_whether_a_set_of_cart_items_contains_a_product_and_a_null_set_is_passed.<.ctor>b__3()
    in CartItemQuerySpecs.cs: line 66
```

The specification looks like this:

```
[Subject(typeof(ShoppingCartQueries), "Cart contains product")]
public class When_testing_whether_a_set_of_cart_items_contains_a_product_and_a_null_set_is_passed
    : with_fake_shopping_cart_repository
    {
    Establish context = () => QueryResult = CartItems.AsQueryable().ForUser(UserWithNoProductsInCart);
    Because of = () => Thrown = Catch.Exception(() => result = QueryResult.ContainsProduct(100));
    It should_throw = () => Thrown.ShouldBeOfType<ArgumentNullException>();
    static bool result;
    }
```

The unit under test looks like this:

```
[Pure]
public static bool ContainsProduct(this IQueryable<CartItem> items, int id)
    {
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(items != null);
    return (items.Any(item => item.ProductId.Equals(id)));
    }
```

Why would I get a `MethodAccessException`?

Comment: You could write the MethodAccessException to a log file and analyze its message and stack trace.

Comment: If you have a complete repro, we can debug it and find a solution. What version of the tools are you using?

Comment: I've just upgraded my tools to VS2012 update 2 and all the current versions of Code Contracts, and not had a chance to try to repro it yet with these tools. I will let you know if I can repro it.